# How do I fadeIn and fadeOut and improve my current JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to javascript.

I want a click on `.direction` to make my `.lightboxbg` and `.directionslightbox` fade in.
When my `.lightboxbg` is clicked I want my `.lightboxbg` and `.directionslightbox` to fade out.

I also want to make sure when my `.lightboxbg` and `.directionslightbox` has faded in that my `.contactlist` hides but shows again when it has faded out.

My HTML:

```
<div class="contactmenu">
  <nav>
    <ul class= "contactlist">
      <li style="background-image:url('directions.png');" class="directions">
      </li>
      <li style="background-image:url('callicon.png');" class="">
       <a href="tel:+44(0)1392495573"></a>
      </li>
      <li style="background-image:url('email.png');" class="">
        <a href="mailto:matt050681@gmail.com"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="lightboxbg"></div>
<div class="directionslightbox"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.lightbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 45%;
    background: center no-repeat #fff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;
}
div.directionslightbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left:18%;
    background:url("../Map_Background_Web.png"); center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 65%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;
}
div.lightboxbg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}
```

My current JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.directions').click(function() {
        $('.lightboxbg, .directionslightbox').fadeIn(800);
    });
    $('.lightboxbg').click(function() {
        $('.lightboxbg, .directionslightbox').fadeOut(800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have been stuck on it for ages.

Comment: when its display:none event handlers wont get attached.

Comment: Right, does that mean I should take this out? The current Script works however I want to just put in the part I mentioned about the ".contactlist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".directions", function() {
  $('.lightboxbg, .directionslightbox').fadeIn(800);
  $('.contactlist').fadeOut("slow");
  });
  $(document).on("click",".lightboxbg", function() {
  $('.lightboxbg, .directionslightbox').fadeOut(800);
  $('.contactlist').fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: This is great however the ".contact" list doesnt hide when faded in and show when faded out

Comment: perfect, I see it required an extra line. Great work